# Strapi: How to include/populate relations with fetch call?

Tags: fetch, content-management-system, strapi

I'm trying to make a "related articles" for a "blog-article" single based off the relation "blog-categories", but I can't seem to get the relations to appear in the api call.
What's the API url with the correct parameters to get relations with Strapi?

To populate all of the articles in descending order by date with images, I'm doing:

```
const res = 
   await fetch (
       https://localhost:3000/api/blog-articles?populate=*&sort[0]=publishDate%3Adesc
   )
```

[Collection's Content Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH73C.png)

Edit: [Fetch result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgTQv.png)
Edit 2: [Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0tjw.png)

Comment: Sorry, the question is a bit unclear. So you have 2 collections i.e `blog-articles` & `blog-categories` which are related with `many-to-many` relation. What do you need in your response of fetch API? What do you mean by 'I'm trying to make a "related articles" for a "blog-article" single based off the relation "blog-categories"?'

Comment: @Salvino Sorry for the unclear question. My question is: how do I get the related blog-categories field of blog-articles with the api fetch call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by passing the related field name in the `populate` http query string.

###### HTTP Request URL

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/blog-articles?populate=blog_categories&sort[0]=publishedAt%3Adesc
```

###### JS Implementation

```js
const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/blog-articles?populate=blog_categories&sort[0]=publishedAt%3Adesc');
const data = await resp.json();
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Shows the same information as before, except without the thumbnail information this time.

Comment: Could you post your blog-articles model setting json file in your question?

Comment: Added the schema.json file to the original post. 
Here's the specific field:
"attributes": {
    "blog_categories": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToMany",
      "target": "api::blog-category.blog-category",
      "inversedBy": "blog_articles"
    },

Comment: Yep, my query seems to be correct. Could you check for the data in categories? Check if there are published records..